# How to solve the problem KeyError: "['Label'] not found in axis"?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on network traffic classification using `tf.keras`. I want to drop a column name **Label** and set **Label as Y** and **all other columns in X**. I am using pandas. here is the code line:

```
df =df.drop(['Label'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
----> 1 df =df.drop(['Label'], axis=1, inplace=True)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
5285 if mask.any():
5286 if errors != "ignore":
-> 5287 raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
5288 indexer = indexer[~mask]
5289 return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: "['Label'] not found in axis"
```

I have tried different methods but failed. anyone of you kindly help to get rid of this situation.

Comment: could you print just the head of `df`?

Comment: Use `df =df.drop(['Label'], axis=1)` or `df.drop(['Label'], axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: @Anwarvic yes i have tried both. Nothing has worked yet :(